# Reload/refresh the DOM with new elements that are created after an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, browser, refresh

I want to access elements that were created after some event. These elements were missing in the original DOM.
For example-

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('some class name');
//do some event to open a new div popup
var newInput = document.getElementsByClassName('new class name in the new div popup');
```

Now, how do I access the newInput?

If I don't do anything it will be `undefined`. If I can reload/refresh the DOM somehow then I will be able to access these new elements.

`location.reload();` won't work because it will refresh the whole page and all my previous values will be lost, like  `inputs`

The new `div` is appended when a button is clicked.

Before click event:

```
<div class="some class name"></div>
```

After click event:

```
<div class="some class name"></div>
<div class="new class name in the new div popup"></div>
```

Comment: You're question is not clear, are you asking how to add some new elements to the `DOM` programmatically? Please give more detail to this: `//do some event to open a new div popup`

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) is always useful.

Comment: Show us the code which opens the popup. If it happen synchroneous the elements should already be visible when u assign `newInput`. Otherwise i would assume there happens something async.

Comment: Are you running the query when the pages loads? Try to run the query after the elements are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a MutationObserver to observe a specific DOM element and execute logic if the condition within the MutationObserver is met: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

In simple words:

1. Observe e.g. a 'parent' element which 'receives' the DOM elements you want to target
2. The MutationObserver will run whenever your new elements get inserted and allow you to run your custom code based on that
3. In case you don't need to continue watching the elements with the MutationObserver after it's use you can also disconnect the Observer.

Comment: ...awesome....its working.....just one minor issue.....I am modifying the element that I am observing so it goes in an infinite loop....is there a way to stop the observation after acknowledging the observation for the first time......

Comment: it's hard to give advise without seeing the code. When exactly does it go into an infinite loop? Generally you can disconnect the observer at any time. Just reference your observer and write a condition under which it should disconnect.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/disconnect

Maybe you also could prevent the loop by filtering the circumstances under which the custom code is run in your observer? If you look at the example from the Mozilla Docs you see mutation of mutationsList. Log the mutation to see what options for specifying your conditions exist.